# InterSystems Caché - How to get access to Caché Studio?

Tags: database, authentication, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am a Caché admin so I have have all access to the system managment portal. I would like to use Caché studio but my login doesn't seem to be setup properly for that. I am new to Caché, only been using it for 2 months now, I am learning the Jargon. So things may be flying over my head as I sift through manuals. 
Is it possible for me to create the credentials in the system management portal so that I may access Caché Studio?

I'm using Caché 2010.2 and I have Caché Studio and Terminal installed.

From my research, I have gathered:
To log in to Studio, you need to use a user who holds the following privileges: %Development:Use and %Service_Object:Use

My system management portal (SMP) Id has %all privileges and I added in those 2 privledges for the heck of it to no avail.

You can only connect to a namespace that you have R/W permission to in the default database.
Our database is used by one application. I already have R/W for the application database. When I open up Studio, the only namespace that I see is: CACHE (localhost(1972)). I assume that it's the whole system database. I then granted my Id R/W access to it to no avail. Also everything is happening locally, I am doing all of this on the db server.

I tried the default logins (leaving Username and Password blank) and the default system login, to no avail.
I am the only one at my organization administering this database.

I would like to gain access to our own Caché studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Caché cube -> Preferred server -> Add/Edit
- Add the server with the System Management Portal (SMP) here. Give it any name, copy the IP.
- Set ports to 1972(1973), 23, 57772(57773), authentication to password, everything else blank.

If I'm right, you have the SMP address in browser's bookmarks, not the Caché cube. When you do this, you should be able to open Studio from Caché cube and SMP or Terminal, too.

If the ports differ, try to find the right ports in the SMP. The portal changed a lot, so I can't really say where you should look for it, I have Ensemble 2012 on my work PC.

Comment: @JIM GAUL - in case it was you who upvoted me and it works, please select the answer as the best answer. It tells the others that the question is already answered. (I'd write that to the question itself, but I don't have the rights yet.)

Comment: Yeah that's right, I access the SMP portal via browser bookmark but when I am on the database server, I access the SMP through the caché cube. I went to the menu option and I can see the default connection called CACHE with all the same port numbers and setup exactly the same way as you had described.

Comment: I went ahead and setup another connection anyway to the db server to no avail. I still get access denied.

Everyone is giving good solutions and may help others having these issues; however, I am still unable to access Caché studio.

Comment: So, the server's cube should have the right settings at least for the SMP. Try using Studio on the server, too. If it is a Windows server (I never had it on Linux, but I suppose there is not the same cube in Linux), it should at least tell you there is some problem with your account.

Comment: If the server's cube gets you to the right place, look at its settings (in the Add/Edit) and copy the settings to your local Caché instance. Just change the hostname from localhost to the server's IP or DNS name.

Comment: Yeah, I have access to the SMP also yes I'm using win7. Full access (%All), so there's got to be some way I could set myself up with access to Caché studio. It doesn't make sense to me that my admin account has %All privileges and when I open up Caché studio, I get Access Denied even when I try logging in with my SMP admin account. I am new to Caché, I don't know if I need a seperate Caché studio account or if my SMP account is supposed to work.

Comment: Wait - I guess you aren't using Win7 on the server. What I proposed is to use Remote Desktop on the server, then try to open the studio there.

Comment: Oop, you're right, it's actually on windows server 2008 R2(db server) and I am remoting in. The db server is where all the caché stuff resides (studio, terminal). My admin account is not delegated which means that I have a seperate caché login from my windows logon right. I think the studio is set to only allow delegated access for me. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Are you telling me you can't even login in Studio on the remote desktop, with the same login/password you use in SMP? That is quite surprising. Maybe there is some weird settings, try contacting InterSystems WRC (support).

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right and it is really strange. I have found one solution to my problem, I changed the service setting in SMP to give me access to studio and even the terminal which I did not have access to before. I did it by having it authenticate with a password (caché credential rather then delegated). I just posted it, if you have any other ideas/solutions please share. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Predefined User Accounts](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_users_predefined)
use
login: _SYSTEM
pass: SYS

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that; however, I have already tried that default login and I get access denied when logging in to Caché studio

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to connect to a wrong server. localhost:1972 is your local computer. To add a new server to that list, go to cache cube -> Remote access -> add/delete... and add your real server.

Or, just press "connect..." button in that Studio dialogue and enter server info there.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have that option available (Caché Cube -> Remote Access -> add/delete) Also, I am doing this on the database server itself, so my local computer is what has caché on it. So I don't think there's a problem there. I think it's really strange that I cannot add remote system access though, maybe it could have to do with my accounts priveledges...

Answer (score 0):

click in the bottom of windows bar next to hour. And then you will see Studio in the context menu

welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer (there may be more).

I had no Caché studio and terminal access because these services in the System Management Portal (SMP) under "Home>Security Management>Services"  were set to delegated only: %Service_Bindings and %Service_Console. %Service_Bindings is the service that controlled access to caché studio. My caché admin account is not a delegated account. The default account _SYSTEM is not enabled (Home>Security Management>Users). I have tried enabling the account but something in the background seems to lock it after I do that - I have yet to find out what that is (new to Caché). It's probably not a good idea to have the default account enabled anyways.

Now, after editing the definition for service %Service_Bindings to allow a password authentication method, I can now use my Caché admin credentials to get into Caché Studio.

To edit service defintions through the SMP, follow these menu breadcrumbs: "Home>Security Management>Services" then click on the service that you wish to edit. In Caché 2010.2, there's 3 authentication methods that you can use for each serivce: unauthenticated, password, delegated.

If anyone has a better solution please inform!

Comment: Never heard of delegated access. It seems whoever made this setup did a bad job with handing the server and the codes to you. I think that default settings is unauthenticated and password is quite commonly used. I'd stick to the password and consider it final, at least for now.

Comment: Lol, you bet! You're exactly right, whoever did setup our databases, did a very terrible job and I'm the one that has to cleanup the mess. It took me a while to figure it out and then I finally learned that my account wasn't delegated. I may have this wrong but a delegated account is an account that is linked with your server/system account e.g. windows logon. So I believe it's supposed to log you in automatically; however, I have yet to see this work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my English. When installed, the program asks for a password, write to the SYS. Then you can go without a shed under the account "Admin"